# .htaccess noob rewrite index.html

Tags: .htaccess

Here's my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I need this www.domainname.com/folder-name/

to rewrite/redirect to this

www.domainname.com/folder-name/index.html

without screwing up what's already in htaccess.

So i'm clear...when it's all said and done i want www.domainname.com/folder-name/ to display in the URL bar, but I want the content from index.html to be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in that if you go to `www.domainname.com/folder-name/`, your first rewrite rule will redirect you to `www.domainname.com/folder-name`, removing the trailing slash. Assuming you haven't turned off `DirectorySlash`, mod_dir will redirect this *back* to `www.domainname.com/folder-name/`, which then triggers the rewrite rule, which triggers mod_dir, etc. If you've turned *off* `DirectorySlash`, that means you've exposed an information disclosure bug (or "feature") which will list the contents of the `folder-name` folder even if `index.html` exists.

So if you really want to be able to go to `www.domainname.com/folder-name/` and not lose the trailing slash, then you need to add a condition to your first rule and then simply allow mod_dir to do its thing:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you've mistyped and you actually want all the trailing slashes to get removed including for folders, leaking the folder contents and all, then you've got to do a bunch of other things. Essentially, you have to do what mod_dir normall does for you anyways and make sure `DirectorySlash` is turned off (still dangerous, as it could expose the file listings of all your folders):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/index.html [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!  I tried adding DirectoryIndex index.html  It ends up at www.domainname.com/folder-name (without the trailing slash) with a "redirect loop" error.

Comment: @s15199d you include the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
` bit in front of your first rule?